# BigDecimal has scientific notation in soap message

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xsd

I have got strange problem with our webservice.
I have got object OrderPosition which has got a price (which is xsd:decimal with fractionDigits = 9). Apache CXF generate proxy classes for me, and this field is BigDecimal. When I'd like to send value greater than 10000000.00000, this field in soap message has got scientific notation (for example 1.1423E+7).

How can I enforce that the value has not been sent in scientific notation.

Comment: What binding (e.g jaxb etc) are you using ?

Comment: I use jaxb for xml binding. And this field has got annotation:
    @XmlElement(name = "NetPrice", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal netPrice;

Comment: See https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/386 Maybe you are using an old version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way this can be done.

`BigDecimal` has a constructor which takes input number as a string. This when used, preservs the input formatting when its `.toString()` method is called.  e.g.

> ```
> BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("10000000.00000");
> System.out.println(bd);
> ```

will print `10000000.00000`.

This can be leveraged in **`Jaxb XmlAdapters`**. Jaxb XmlAdapters offer a convenient way to **control/customize the marshalling/unmashalling process**. A typical adapter for `BigDecimmal` would look like as follows.

```
public class BigDecimalXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter{

    @Override
    public String marshal(BigDecimal bigDecimal) throws Exception {
        if (bigDecimal != null){
            return bigDecimal.toString();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal unmarshal(String s) throws Exception {
        try {
            return new BigDecimal(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This needs to be registered with Jaxb context. [Here is the link](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/09/06/solving-unmarshalling-problems-with-jaxbcxf/) with complete example.

Comment: `toPlainString()` is the method that will print the value without a scientific notation conversion.

Answer (score 0):

@Santosh Thank you! XMLAdapter was what I needed.
Furthermore as I said in my question I generate client classes with Apache CXF. In this kind of problem I had to add the following code to bindings.xjb (binding file which is use to cxf-codegen-plugin in maven).

```xml
<jaxb:javaType  name="java.math.BigDecimal" xmlType="xs:decimal"
    parseMethod="sample.BigDecimalFormater.parseBigDecimal"
    printMethod="sample.BigDecimalFormater.printBigDecimal" />
```

This is my formatter code:

```
public class BigDecimalFormater {
    public static String printBigDecimal(BigDecimal value) {
        value.setScale(5);

        return value.toPlainString();
    }

    public static BigDecimal parseBigDecimal(String value) {
        return new BigDecimal(value);
    }
}
```

Then this plugin generate Adapter for me

```
public class Adapter1 extends XmlAdapter<String, BigDecimal> {
    public BigDecimal unmarshal(String value) {
        return (sample.BigDecimalFormater.parseBigDecimal(value));
    }
    public String marshal(BigDecimal value) {
        return (sample.BigDecimalFormater.printBigDecimal(value));
    }
}
```

In generated class BigDecimal field has got annotation @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class), and it resolved problem.