# Apache Axis 1: Disable serialization of xsd:float in scientific notation

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, axis

We have a webservice client that calls a service (rpc-encoded, the reason we are still using Axis 1) that defines some values as `xsd:float` but refuses values passed in scientific notation. I understand that it is totally standard compliant behaviour of the client (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/ 3.2.4.1) and probably it would be the right way for the server to use `xsd:decimal` I  wonder if there is a way to tell axis not to use scientific notation for `xsd:float` and `xsd:double`

Possibly related: [BigDecimal has scientific notation in soap message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115521/bigdecimal-has-scientific-notation-in-soap-message) asks how to achieve this with JAX-B with the accepted answer suggesting to use an `XMLAdapter`. Maybe there exists a similar mechanism for axis.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in Axis (http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#XML_-_Java_Data_Mapping_in_Axis), you can define your own serializer and deserializer for (e.g.) float (you will have to change the xsd: ; do you have access?).  This is done via a typeMapping:

```
<typeMapping qname="ns:local" xmlns:ns="someNamespace"
    languageSpecificType="java:my.java.thingy"
    serializer="my.java.Serializer"
    deserializer="my.java.DeserializerFactory"
    encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
```

Comment: Can this typeMapping be applied to primitive types? If possible I would try to avoid changing the xsd because sometimes we get updates. If changing the xsd is necessary I guess that changing the floats to decimals would do the trick, wouldn't it?

Comment: If the field is nillable then it is autoboxed into Float.

Comment: It's non nillable in my case. So I guess there is no viable alternative to changing the xsd.